# FFMPEG curtain effect slideshow from images

Tags: ffmpeg

I have bunch of images that i have to convert to slideshow with curtain effect. currently i am running this command that convert images to video.

```
ffmpeg -r 1/5 -i img%d.png -c:v libx264 -vf "fps=25,format=yuv420p" video.mp4
```

But how to achieve this kind of effect with ffmpeg. Image link [Required result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZRew.gif)

I searched online but not found any solution. I have clue of alpha mask but no idea how to use it for such result.

Comment: `melt`, a command-line editor, would be easier for this task. Use the luma wipe plugin with a white/black/white reflected gradient to direct the wipe.

Comment: thanks @llogan for help, i solved using ffmpeg by this command

ffmpeg -y -i img1.png -i img2.png -i img3.png -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='zoom+0.0000':d=50[img1];[1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0030))':d=200[img2];[img1][img2]blend=all_expr='if(lte((H/2-sqrt((Y-H/2)*(Y-H/2)))+N*8*SH,H/2),A,B)'[img1img2];[1:v]zoompan=z='zoom+0.0000':d=50[img2];[2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0030))':d=200[img3];[img2][img3]blend=all_expr='if(lte((H/2-sqrt((Y-H/2)*(Y-H/2)))+N*8*SH,H/2),A,B)'[img2img3];[img1img2][img2img3]concat=n=2[final]" -map "[final]" out.mp4

Comment: Since you found a solution you can add it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -y -i img1.png -i img2.png -i img3.png -filter_complex "[0:v]zoompan=z='zoom+0.0000':d=50[img1];[1:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0030))':d=200[img2];[img1][img2]blend=all_expr='if(lte((H/2-sqrt((Y-H/2)*(Y-H/2)))+N*8*SH,H/2),A,B)'[img1img2];[1:v]zoompan=z='zoom+0.0000':d=50[img2];[2:v]zoompan=z='if(lte(zoom,1.0),1.1,max(1.001,zoom-0.0030))':d=200[img3];[img2][img3]blend=all_expr='if(lte((H/2-sqrt((Y-H/2)*(Y-H/2)))+N*8*SH,H/2),A,B)'[img2img3];[img1img2][img2img3]concat=n=2[final]" -map "[final]" out.mp4
```

This ffmpeg command will generate door open (curtain) effect. 
Here is logic.
Suppose you have there images you want to create this effect. First create blend effect of first img1 and img2. Then create another blend effect with img2 and img3. then merge these 2 generated videos.